# What is the reason for padding-right 40px in Material-UI TableCell-root

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am just curious what is the reason for it. I am planning to override it, 
just want to make sure I don't eliminate someone's thorough work.

```
.MuiTableCell-root {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 14px 40px 14px 16px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.43;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
    letter-spacing: 0.01071em;
    vertical-align: inherit;
```

What's interesting that

```
.MuiTableCell-root:last-child {
    padding-right: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Because they decided it should be like that.

Comment: @josemartindev well, I know I can do that, I just thought It might be something which holds a consistent layout and without it, the layout would break on some screen dimension or some other corner case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the current spec: https://material.io/design/components/data-tables.html#specs

I don't see anything in the spec that specifically mentions this 40px padding explicitly, though the example does show considerable space between columns.

I think the purpose is just to have an aesthetically pleasing amount of space between the data in adjacent cells and to improve readability. If you use `size="small"` on the table, the amount of padding is significantly reduced (24px for the padding-right).